# Determine HTML page that called a function in an external js file

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to determine this at runtime?

contents of external.js:

```
function x() {

  //can i get the path/name of the html file that included this js file?

  //which is test.html

}
```

contents of test.html

script src="external.js"

Answer (score 5):

The “HTML file that *included* this js file” is easy, it's simply the address of the current document. `location.href`.

If you want to get a particular part of the URL, eg. the last part of the pathname:

```
var filename= location.pathname.split('/').pop();
```

The HTML page that *called* a function is a slightly different proposition, because in the world of cross-document scripting you can pass a function from one window to another, and so call the function from a different place to that where it was defined.

There's no simple or reliable way to detect where you've been *called* from, but this situation is generally not that common. In general it's best to avoid cross-document function calling as there are a number of nasty traps. `window.postMessage` should reduce the need for this in the future.

Comment: +1, I wish I hadn't wasted time formatting his code now lol ;-)

Comment: +1.. simple answer. @UICodes: When your JS code is executed, it runs as part of whatever file included it. So getting the current document address will give you the file that included it.

Comment: lol, sorry Andy's head! And sorry Senthil, I made the answer less simple, as the question in the title is subtly different from the question in the main text...